# Finding the nth partial sum of a telescoping series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left[\frac{2}{\left(n+1\right)}-\frac{2}{\left(n+3\right)}\right]$

This question is off from webwork and I already got everything right except for finding the nth partial sum. Here is what I have:

s3 = 1 + 2/3 - 2/5 - 2/6

s4 = 1 + 2/3 - 2/6 - 2/7

s5 = 1 + 2/3 - 2/7 - 2/8

It converges to 1 + 2/3

Now my nth partial sum is: 1 + 2/3 - 2/(n+1) - 2/(n+2)

But it seems to be incorrect. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sum up to $n$ the surviving negative terms are $\frac 2{n+2}$ and $\frac 2{n+3}$.  See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(2%2F(n%2B1)-2%2F(n%2B3))%20from%201%20to%2010) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B2%2F3-2%2F12-2%2F13) for $n=10$.  You are off by $1$ in the denominators.